# Query to sort upcoming dates first, ascending, then past dates, descending

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I have a event table which stored date (m/d/Y) in a following manner

```
eventid     eventstart      eventend    status
----------------------------------------------
      1     10/9/2012       10/27/2012  Active
      2     4/3/2012        4/27/2012   Active
      3     10/26/2012      10/27/2012  Active
      4     2/7/2012        2/9/2012    Active
      5     10/30/2012      10/31/2012  Active
      6     10/9/2012       10/31/2012  Active
      7     11/9/2012       10/19/2012  Active
      8     10/31/2012      10/18/2012  Active
```

If I have an input date e.g. 10/29/2012 then I want to sort the startdate in the following manner

```
eventstart          
----------
10/30/2012
10/31/2012 
11/9/2012
10/26/2012
10/9/2012
10/9/2012
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What about the `4/3` and `2/7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CASE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) in the order by clause to sort the two cases separately:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `events`
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN eventstart >= '2012-10-29' THEN eventstart ELSE '9999-12-31' END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN eventstart <  '2012-10-29' THEN eventstart ELSE NULL         END DESC

-- eventid | eventstart
-- --------+-----------
-- 5       | 2012-10-30
-- 8       | 2012-10-31
-- 7       | 2012-11-09
-- 3       | 2012-10-26
-- 1       | 2012-10-09
-- 6       | 2012-10-09
-- 2       | 2012-04-03
-- 4       | 2012-02-07
```

Comment: hi thnx 4 query..i have modified this query as follows : SELECT *
FROM `event`
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN eventstart >= '10/29/2012' THEN eventstart ELSE '12/31/9999' END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN eventstart <  '10/29/2012' THEN eventstart ELSE NULL         END DESC and output as follows            10/30/2012  
10/30/2012  
10/31/2012  
11/9/2012  
10/26/2012  
10/09/2012  
2/7/2012  
4/3/2012  

CAN U HELP ME

Comment: The output looks similar to the one you posted in your question except the last two values. If you are storing dates as VARCHAR then it is a _bad_ idea.

Answer (score 1):

In a really schematic way:

```
select * from tablename where eventstart >= '10/29/2012' order by eventstart asc
union
select * from tablename where eventstart < '10/29/2012' order by eventstart desc
```

The first line would get the unstarted events, ordered ascending, and the third one would get the rest.

You should then manage to truly compare those dates with a SQL function or so, and to decide if you want to include today as an *unstarted* event or as a *past* event. I posted the first case. If you want today to be a past event, remove the equal symbol from the first comparison and move it to the second one:

```
select * from tablename where eventstart > '10/29/2012' order by eventstart asc
union
select * from tablename where eventstart <= '10/29/2012' order by eventstart desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from event where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM str_to_date(eventstart, '%d/%m/%Y'))>=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM str_to_date('10/29/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'))
and eventstart >'10/29/2012'
union
select * from event where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM str_to_date(eventstart, '%d/%m/%Y'))>=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM str_to_date('10/29/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'))
and eventstart <'10/29/2012'
```

Comment: yh appreciate your query frnd.But it showing a syntax error while executing.